# In Swift, how do I write a protocol which exposes another generic protocol?

Tags: swift

Something like this:

```
protocol MyCollection {
    var collection:Collection where Collection.Element == Int { get }
}
```

I want a ‘MyCollection’ type to expose a collection of Ints, where the actual type of collection is private. Only the methods in the Collection protocol are available on collection property.

Answer (score 1):

As of [SE-0142: Permit where clauses to constrain associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md) you can blueprint an `associatedtype` in you protocol and put constraints on it, thereafter blueprint the `collection` variable to be declared as the constrained `associatedtype`:

```
protocol MyCollection {
    associatedtype C : Collection where C.Element == Int
    var collection: C { get }
}
```

Examples:

```
// OK: C inferred as [Int] which fulfills the constraint on the associated type
struct Foo: MyCollection {
    var collection = [Int]()
}

// error: type 'Bar' does not conform to protocol 'MyCollection'
// note: protocol requires nested type 'C'; do you want to add it?
struct Bar: MyCollection {
    var collection = [Float]()
}

// error: 'MyCollection' requires the types 'Float' and 'Int' be equivalent
// note: requirement specified as 'Self.C.Element' == 'Int' [with Self = Baz]
struct Baz: MyCollection {
    typealias C = [Float]
    var collection: C = []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want a ‘MyCollection’ type to expose a collection of Ints, where the actual type of collection is private

You can’t. You cannot use a generic protocol  as a type (e.g. as the declared type of a variable or parameter). A generic protocol plain and simple is not a type.

The only place you can use a generic protocol plain and simple is as a constraint.